# WPF DataGrid binding to list and sub-list

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, datagrid

I have a list of `Bin` objects with `Id`, `Name` and a  `List<int>` properties which I load as the `ItemsSource` of a `ComboBox`, and a `DataGrid` with a `List<Part>` objects with an `Id` and `Name` properties.

Now I can select the single element via the ComboBox.
I want to update the DataGrid to show only the elements which are in the list of the first `Bin` object, and I want to show the `Id`, not the `Name`.

Unfortunately I have not found anything about this problem. Perhaps I have overlooked something. Here is my code:

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="DataGridBinding.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataGridBinding"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="200" Width="400">

    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">

            <ComboBox Name="CmbList" Height="23" Width="180" Margin="6">
                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ComboBox>

            <DataGrid x:Name="DtgItems" Width="350" Margin="6" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
                      SelectedValue="{Binding ElementName=CmbList, Path=SelectedItem.ItemsNr}">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Id}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>

        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace DataGridBinding
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            this.CmbList.ItemsSource = new List<Bin>
            {
                new Bin
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    Name = "Object One",
                    ItemsNr = new List<int> { 1, 3, 5, }
                },
                new Bin
                {
                    Id = 2,
                    Name = "Object Two",
                    ItemsNr = new List<int> { 2, 4, 6, }
                },
                new Bin
                {
                    Id = 3,
                    Name = "Object Three",
                    ItemsNr = new List<int> { 7, 8, 9, }
                },
                new Bin
                {
                    Id = 4,
                    Name = "Object Four",
                    ItemsNr = new List<int> { 4, 8 }

                },
            };

            this.DtgItems.DataContext = new List<Part>
            {
                new Part { Id = 1, Name = "One" },
                new Part { Id = 2, Name = "Two" },
                new Part { Id = 3, Name = "Three" },
                new Part { Id = 4, Name = "Four" },
                new Part { Id = 5, Name = "Five" },
                new Part { Id = 6, Name = "Six" },
                new Part { Id = 7, Name = "Seven" },
                new Part { Id = 8, Name = "Eight" },
                new Part { Id = 9, Name = "Nine" },
            };

            this.CmbList.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }

    public class Bin
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<int> ItemsNr { get; set; }
    }

    public class Part
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example:

```
<Window x:Class="DataGridBinding.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataGridBinding"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="200" Width="400">

    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">

            <ComboBox Name="CmbList" Height="23" Width="180" Margin="6" SelectionChanged="CmbList_SelectionChanged">
                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ComboBox>

            <DataGrid x:Name="DtgItems" Width="350" Margin="6"
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>

        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace DataGridBinding
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            CmbList.ItemsSource = Bins;
            DtgItems.ItemsSource = Parts;
        }
        List<Bin> Bins = new List<Bin>
        {
            new Bin
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "Object One",
                ItemsNr = new List<int> { 1, 3, 5, }
            },
            new Bin
            {
                Id = 2,
                Name = "Object Two",
                ItemsNr = new List<int> { 2, 4, 6, }
            },
            new Bin
            {
                Id = 3,
                Name = "Object Three",
                ItemsNr = new List<int> { 7, 8, 9, }
            },
            new Bin
            {
                Id = 4,
                Name = "Object Four",
                ItemsNr = new List<int> { 4, 8 }

            },
        };
        List<Part> Parts = new List<Part>
        {
            new Part { Id = 1, Name = "One" },
            new Part { Id = 2, Name = "Two" },
            new Part { Id = 3, Name = "Three" },
            new Part { Id = 4, Name = "Four" },
            new Part { Id = 5, Name = "Five" },
            new Part { Id = 6, Name = "Six" },
            new Part { Id = 7, Name = "Seven" },
            new Part { Id = 8, Name = "Eight" },
            new Part { Id = 9, Name = "Nine" },
        };
        public class Bin
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public List<int> ItemsNr { get; set; }
        }
        public class Part
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
        private void CmbList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            DtgItems.ItemsSource = Parts.Where(t => t.Id == ((Bin)CmbList.SelectedItem).Id);
        }
}
```

The things to note here are the added event handler `CmbList_SelectionChanged` which is triggered when the `ComboBox` selection changes, which updates the `ItemsSource` property of your grid to be only items with a matching `Id`.

You were using the `SelectedIndex` property, which isn't the same as the `Id`. The index is zero based, where as the id isn't.

Needless to say that, altough the code works, there are better ways to approach this problem. I would recommend you look into the [MVVM pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern) and [DataBinding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-5.0), although a code-behind approach is definetly valid as well. Good luck.